# Logging Java Exceptions in Chef

Tags: java, chef-infra, chef-solo

I am invoking a jar using chef like :

```
execute "publish" do
  Chef::Log.info("About to published")
  command "java -jar myjar.jar"
  Chef::Log.info("Published")      
end
```

Now in case while executing myjar, it throws an exception, the same is not visible on the console. Is there some way by which the same can be viewed in the console itself ?

Comment: You should probably be running this as a service with output going to a log file.

Comment: Does it have to be on the console?  You can do: command "java -jar myjar.jar > myoutput.txt" and then view myoutput.txt.

Comment: The only way I think of is using a ruby_block and the `Chef::Mixin.shellout`  but it's pretty ugly and sounds code smell, with more details on the use case we could give better advice.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Chef does not provide any mechanism to view the output of a command diect. The workaround is to write to a file & then read from it.

```
output  = "/tmp/output.tmp"


execute "publish" do
  Chef::Log.info("About to published")
  command command "java -jar myjar.jar &> #{output}"
  action :run
  Chef::Log.info("Published")
end

# Outputting logs to console
ruby_block "log" do
    block do
        print "\n"
        File.open(output).each do |line|
            print line
        end
    end
end
```